# Visio 2010 toggle layer dynamically

Tags: visio

I have multiple layers in a visio document.
One overview layer and some "detailed" layers.
What I would like to do is double click a shape in the overview layer (layer 1) and toggle the  detail layer (layer 2) (so when clicking the shape in layer 1, layer 1 should become invisible and layer 2 should become visible).

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in visio 2010?
I have searched around the internet and the only thing I found was to add the following formula to the shape's shapesheet "EventDblClick", but I get the errormessage "Error in Formula":

```
 =SETF(GetRef(ThePage!Layers[1].Visible),NOT(ThePage!Layers.Visible))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For setting property of layer put ID after property

```
 =SETF(GetRef(ThePage!Layers.Visible[1]),NOT(ThePage!Layers.Visible))
```